# How to call function after node saved drupal 7 php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, drupal-7

I've created a module which uses node_insert();
here the module posts to the Facebook as soon as the node gets created.

problem is that Facebook parses the link before the "Link is even created in Drupal website"...
and Facebook shows page not found

Is there any other workaround?

Or, How can i call function say after x seconds?

PS:I'm using Graph Api

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at 'Hook Post Action' module: https://www.drupal.org/project/hook_post_action.

You can also create some list in your DB or PHP and process your list on cron run.